# Getting My Location Null pointer in Fragment in GoogleMap API v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to get my location on click of save button & store that in
database.

**Problem:**

When I'm trying to get my location it shows me null pointer exception.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong in my code?

**My code:**

```
public class OthersFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
         View view;

        private GoogleMap mMap;
         GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        Double latitude;
        Double longitude;
        String strplace;

        public static OthersFragment newInstance() {
            OthersFragment fragment = new OthersFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
    //                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
    //                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    //                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    //                .build();

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_other, null, false);
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            mMap = googleMap;

            // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {

                    Location mylocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                    ShowPopUp(mylocation);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);


        }

        private void ShowPopUp(final Location mylocation) {

            int popupWidth = 300;
            int popupHeight = 150;

            // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
            LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.popup);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, viewGroup);

            // Creating the PopupWindow
            final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow();
            popup.setContentView(layout);
            popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
            popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
            popup.setFocusable(true);

            // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
            int OFFSET_X = 30;
            int OFFSET_Y = 30;

            // Clear the default translucent background
            popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

            // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
            popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, + OFFSET_X,  OFFSET_Y);

            // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
            Button save = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.save);
            Button retrieve = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.retrieve);
            final EditText place = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.place);
            final EditText phone = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.phone);

            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                      String action = "save";
                      String strplace = place.getText().toString();
                      String strphone = phone.getText().toString();
                    new storePoints().execute(strplace,String.valueOf(mylocation.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(mylocation.getLongitude()), action);
                    popup.dismiss();

                }
            });

            retrieve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String action = "retrieve";
                    strplace = place.getText().toString();
                    String strphone = phone.getText().toString();
                    new retrievePoints().execute(strplace, action);
                    popup.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }


        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

        private class storePoints extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {
                    String place = (String) params[0];
                  //  String phone = (String) params[1];
                    String latitude = (String) params[1];
                    String longitude = (String) params[2];
                    String action = (String) params[3];

                    String link = "http://192.168.0.152/prestige/saveCoord.php";
                    // String link = "http://10.0.2.2/coordinates/coord.php";

                    String data = URLEncoder.encode("station_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(place, "UTF-8");
                   // data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("phone", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8");
                    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("latitude", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(latitude, "UTF-8");
                    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("longitude", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(longitude, "UTF-8");

                    URL url = new URL(link);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                    wr.write(data);
                    wr.flush();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    // Read Server Response
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }
                    return sb.toString();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                Toast.makeText(OthersFragment.this.getContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        }


        private class retrievePoints extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {
                    String place = (String) params[0];
                    String phone = (String) params[1];

                    String link = "http://192.168.0.152/prestige/retCoord.php";
                    // String link = "http://10.0.2.2/coordinates/retCoord.php";

                    String data = URLEncoder.encode("station_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(place, "UTF-8");
                    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("phone", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8");


                    URL url = new URL(link);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                    wr.write(data);
                    wr.flush();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    // Read Server Response
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }
                    return sb.toString();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {

                    mMap.clear(); // clear all the markers on the map.
                    JSONArray loc_arr = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < loc_arr.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject loc_obj = loc_arr.getJSONObject(i);
                        Double  latitude = Double.valueOf((loc_obj.getString("latitude")));
                        Double  longitude = Double.valueOf((loc_obj.getString("longitude")));
                        String place = loc_obj.getString("station_name");
                        //                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "latitude: "+latitude +"\t Longitude: " + longitude+"\t Place: "+place, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        Marker marker= mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Place: "+place).snippet("Latitude: " +latitude+",Longitude: "+longitude));
                        marker.showInfoWindow();

                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),28));

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }


    }
```

**Error Log:**

```
 06-20 12:30:42.740    6682-6682/com.example.barbegambino.apslocate E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.barbegambino.apslocate, PID: 6682
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.barbegambino.apslocate.fragments.OthersFragment$2.onClick(OthersFragment.java:166)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18789)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Log cat report clearly stating that its NullPointerException. So check mylocation param is null or not. If not null do your function. Also try to get the last know location after google api client got connected. So move your getLastLocation code part to onConnected part.

Answer (score 0):

For example try to get last-known location like below,

```
public class MapExample extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
else{
  mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        // work with your last location.
    } else { 
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
}

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this and it worked for me.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry, null, false);

       //added

    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Google Play Services is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        getActivity().finish();
    }

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return view;
}
```

This also i added

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getContext());
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), 0).show();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Google Play Services is not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```